# dynamic goto in oracle plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a procedure that updates ~700 rows from a table based on certain dates.
I want, if the procedure crashes from some reason to restart the procedure from where it left, not from the beginтing ( ex: go to row214).

If I try something like this:

```
begin

goto &label;

<N1>;

dbms_output.put_line(1);

<N2>;

dbms_output.put_line(2);

end;
```

it works, but that will presume human interaction, and I would want the procedure to do this automatically.

How can I do something like this without the ampersand(&)?
If I declare the label as a variable, it doesn't work, or I don't know how to make it work.

Comment: You might want to consider changing the Logic. PL/SQL Blocks are not quite meant to have direct human interaction during run-time.
Your Procedure should have separate "Logical Units" so it can be re-run.

Comment: Create special table for update status. Instead of lables wrap logic into if-then statements checking update-status. Update status and commit after step is done. Next step will see status update and run normally. On re-run first N steps will be skipped. Manual interaction is required if something is commited wrongly - in this case you need to reset/change update status in your table.

Comment: The question is about  how you can go the goto dynamically, I know you can, but I don't know how, the trouble is how you can declare the label as a variable.

Comment: How do you "know you can"? I think most of us are pretty sure you can't. It's an interesting problem though - you have a sequence of processing steps that you would like to be able to resume from a specified point without wrapping every step in an `if` condition. I can't see a way.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do a "dynamic GOTO" in a static PL/SQL block.  The reason is that any argument that follows the `GOTO` keyword will be interpreted as the label you want to jump to, not as an expression that will evaluate to the label.

About the closest you'll get is this:

```
declare 
  l_label VARCHAR2(30) := 'N2';
BEGIN

 CASE l_label
   WHEN 'N1' THEN GOTO N1;
   WHEN 'N2' THEN GOTO N2;
   ELSE raise_application_error (-20001, 'Unknown label: ' || l_label);
 END CASE;

 <<N1>>
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (1);

 <<N2>>
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (2);
END;
```

Comment: By the way, I don't know the specifics of your process, but for 700 rows being updated, I would seriously consider to just `ROLLBACK` everything in the event of an error, rather than worry about restarting.

Comment: The table is a dashboard with various information that are independent from each other, so I prefer to keep the ones that I already calculated.

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot do this in static PL/SQL, your use of ampersand (&) implies that you might be using SQL*Plus and merely want to avoid having a human have to type in the value of the label at runtime.

In SQL*Plus, you can do this.

```
column label_value old_value label;
set termout off
REM Replace the following SQL with something that will get the correct label.
select 'N2' label_value FROM dual;
set termout on
set verify off

set serveroutput on

begin
  goto &label;
  <<N1>>
  dbms_output.put_line('N1');
  <<N2>>
  dbms_output.put_line('N2');
end;
/
```

Comment: The real question was how can I get rid of the ampersand (&).

Comment: The `select 'N2' label_value FROM dual` loads the label you want to jump to into the `&label` variable.  It does not require human interaction, as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: It does't work (tried it) to select a _value into an ampersand variable.With label_value it asks me to declare the variable label_value, with just label (declared as varchar2) it still asks for the value. Maybe it's something like this, but with a different syntax.

Comment: Matthew's example works fine. You don't need to declare anything, and you don't refer to `label_value` in your PL/SQL block, just `&label`, which SQL*Plus replaces with `N1` or `N2` before sending the block to the database.

Comment: If you leave just & label,  you will be prompted for the value.  I've tested that,  that's the example I begun with.  My problem is how to initialize automatically label with a value from a table, and not to be prompted for the value of label.

Comment: Did you execute everything I posted?  The `column label_value old_value label` is key.  It tells SQL*Plus that whatever I `SELECT` with a column alias of `label_value`, it needs to store into the `&label` variable.  Then, of course, you have to run the `SELECT ... label_value FROM dual;`.  Run what I posted, verbatim, from top to bottom and tell me what you get.  Because for me it works fine.

Comment: I run this from Toad for Oracle, not SQL Plus, and it doesn't recognize the commands before begin. So, I thank you for the solutions, but it does't work for me.